# Converting string to System.IO.Stream

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xamarin

I have created a serializable class and added some objects. 
Now I want an xml file to be created (based on that class) when I click a button, so I did this:

```
private void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = "Data.xml";
            MySerializableClass msc = new MySerializableClass();
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MySerializableClass));
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, Encoding.UTF8); //'filename' is underlined
            serializer.Serialize(sw, msc);
            sw.Close(); //'Close' is underlined
            //'StreamWriter' does not contain a definition for 'Close' [...]
        }
```

Unfortunately I get the following error: *cannot* *convert* *from* *'String'* *to* *'System.IO.Stream'*. What does this mean? I don't get why encoding to UTF8 doesn't work. Using no encoding gives me the same error.

Comment: As a side note, try using a `using` statement on your StreamWriter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

streamwriter constructor parameters wrong ..

```
        string fileName = "your file path";
        using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                MySerializableClass msc = new MySerializableClass();
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MySerializableClass));
                serializer.Serialize(sw, msc);
            }
        }
```

if you want to without FileStream, use this constructor.. StreamWriter(string path, bool append, Encoding encoding)

```
        string fileName = "your file path";
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, true, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            MySerializableClass msc = new MySerializableClass();
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MySerializableClass));
            serializer.Serialize(sw, msc);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Sir! I've never worked with serialization so I just had a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szzyf24s(v=vs.110).aspx and thought it would be that easy. Have a good day!

Comment: Is it possible that there is no "FileStream" in a PCL? I get the "the type or namespace name 'filestream' could not be found" error. Any ideas?

Comment: This definitely doesn't work, I cut and paste that code directly into my program, changing only the variable names as appropriate. I see the same error. The file path passed to StreamWriter generates an error that string cannot be converted to System.IO.Stream

Answer (score 1):

Please see the documentation for `StreamWriter`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx

Try this overload `StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, false, Encoding.UTF8);`

Or you will need to create a Stream from the "data.xml" file, rather than just passing the filename.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I just looked at this example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szzyf24s(v=vs.110).aspx andthought it would work. So how would I have to change the code in order to get the results I want?

Comment: The answer from @levent provides a full solution.  I updated my answer to include the overload which should work for you.  You can also just supply the filename rather than the filename and encoding.

Comment: sw(fileName, false, Encoding.UTF8) won't work either, gotta try @levent's solution but thank you anyway!

Comment: If you can provide more information other than "won't work" I can try to be of further assistance.

Comment: According to VS it should look like this: StreamWriter(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize, bool leaveOpen)

Comment: There are multiple overloads, that is one of them.

Comment: So the problem was that I had written the filename, which is a string instead of a stream.. But then why is msdn suggesting that it should work either way? Am I missing something? (referring link in the first comment)

Comment: It will work either way.  The link you provided uses the overload that just takes the file name (no encoding).  There is also the overload that I provided that takes the file name, Append Boolean, and encoding.